# Programmatically Set an href Link in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, use-effect

I have a product that I want to programatically set a Checkout Session URL and then redirect a user when they click on an  tag.

```
const PlanComponent = () => {

    const [tiers, setTiers] = useState([]);

    async function CheckoutSessionUrl(tierId) {
        var result = null

        await CreateCheckoutSession(
            "PRODUCT_ID", 
            tierId, 
            "UID"
        ).then(function(response) {
            result = response
        })
        return result;
    };

    async function LoadProducts() {
        var result = []
        await GetProducts("PRODUCT_ID").then(function(response) {
          for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) { 
              var tier_id = response[i]["tier_id"]
              CheckoutSessionUrl(tier_id).then(function(tier_response) {
                  response[i]["url"] = tier_response;
              })
          }
          console.log("printing tiers");
          console.log(response);

          return response;
        }).then(function(response){
            result = response;
            setTiers(result)
            return result;
        });
        
        return result;
    
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      // Some initialization logic here
      LoadProducts().then(function(response) {
        console.log("setting tiers")
        console.log(response)
        //setTiers(response)
      })
     
    }, []);


  return (
    <div className="bg-white">
      <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-24 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div className="sm:flex sm:flex-col sm:align-center">
          <h1 className="text-5xl font-extrabold text-gray-900 sm:text-center">Pricing Plans</h1>
          <p className="mt-5 text-xl text-gray-500 sm:text-center">
            Start building for free, then add a site plan to go live. Account plans unlock additional features.
          </p>

        </div>
        <div className="mt-12 space-y-4 sm:mt-16 sm:space-y-0 sm:grid sm:grid-cols-2 sm:gap-6 lg:max-w-4xl lg:mx-auto xl:max-w-none xl:mx-0 xl:grid-cols-4">
          {tiers.map((tier) => (
            <div key={tier.name} className="border border-gray-200 rounded-lg shadow-sm divide-y divide-gray-200">
              <div className="p-6">
                <h2 className="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900">{tier.name}</h2>
                <p className="mt-4 text-sm text-gray-500">{tier.description}</p>
                <p className="mt-8">
                  <span className="text-4xl font-extrabold text-gray-900">${tier.price}</span>{' '}
                  <span className="text-base font-medium text-gray-500">/mo</span>
                </p>
                
                    <a
                    href={tier.url}
                    className="mt-8 block w-full bg-gray-800 border border-gray-800 rounded-md py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white text-center hover:bg-gray-900"
                    >
                    Buy {tier.name}
                    </a>
                
                
              </div>
              <div className="pt-6 pb-8 px-6">
                <h3 className="text-xs font-medium text-gray-900 tracking-wide uppercase">What's included</h3>
                <ul role="list" className="mt-6 space-y-4">
                  {tier.users.map((feature) => (
                    <li key={feature} className="flex space-x-3">
                      {/*<CheckIcon className="flex-shrink-0 h-5 w-5 text-green-500" aria-hidden="true" />*/}
                      <span className="text-sm text-gray-500">{feature}</span>
                    </li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

so if you look at the href={tier.url} it's not being set correctly. I feel like I'm not doing this correctly. Would love some feedback on how to actually get this working properly. IT looks like the tier.url new field isn't being set correctly (doesn't exist in the initial request but all the other attributes work).

The other option I wanted to do was when a user clicked a Button, it would generate a URL and redirect a user to that new external url but the navigation kept breaking.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found out what was happening. I needed to replace

```
 await GetProducts("PRODUCT_ID").then(function(response) {
```

with

```
 await GetProducts("PRODUCT_ID").then(async function(response) {
```